# Oracle - additional column check with min function and group by

Tags: oracle

My Oracle table has the columns: message_id, status, status_date

I would like to return message_id where when grouping by message_id the record with the mininum value for status_date has a value of 'PC' in the status column. 
In other words do not return the record if the record that is returned with the minimum value of status_date when grouped by mess_id does not have a value of 'PC' in the status column.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: Can you post some sample data and some expected output?  I'm afraid that I don't understand quite what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what the source data may look like:

```
message_id status status_date
---------- ------ -----------
         1 PC     01-JAN-12
         1 QC     02-JAN-12
         1 RC     03-JAN-12
         2 AA     04-JAN-12
         2 PC     05-JAN-12
         2 CC     06-JAN-12
         3 PC     07-JAN-12
         3 PC     08-JAN-12
         3 PC     09-JAN-12
```

And that the expected output would be something like this:

```
message_id
----------
         1 
         3
```

The reason that these two records are returned are because for all the records where `message_id=1`, the one with the minimum `status_date` has a value of 01-JAN-12. The record with `message_id=1` and status_date of 01-JAN-12 has a status of 'PC', and similarly with `message_id=3`. Since the minimum `status_date` of the records with `message_id=2` is 04-JAN-12, and it's status is NOT 'PC'.

We can build this query using inline views, but there's probably an easier way using analytic functions.

```
SELECT A.MESSAGE_ID
FROM   MY_TABLE A, 
       (  SELECT B.MESSAGE_ID, MIN(B.STATUS_DATE) MIN_DATE
          FROM MY_TABLE B
          GROUP BY B.MESSAGE_ID ) C
WHERE  A.STATUS = 'PC' 
AND    A.STATUS_DATE = C.STATUS_DATE 
AND    A.MESSAGE_ID = C.MESSAGE_ID;
```